# Form.submit() is not adding URL parameters and redirects to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, forms, apache, dom

I have a simple form that for some reason at a certain customer is not working as expected.

```
<form id="fpForm" method="get" action="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="someHiddenValue" value="2"/>

    Label<br/>

    <input type="text" name="someVisibleValue" value="" size="30"/>

    <br/><br/>

    <a href="#" onclick="document.forms[1].submit();return false;"><span>This button submits</span></a>&nbsp;<a href="login"><span>This one Cancels</span></a><br/><br/>
</form>
```

I didn't write the code, I just have to support it. But anyway...

At other customers and in my test environment when I fill out the text input and click the button to submit the url gets navigated to and it has the parameters as expected:

```
<some_url_I_can't_show_here>/login?someHiddenValue=2&someVisibleValue=value_here
```

But at this customer when I click I get this:

```
<some_url_I_can't_show_here>/login?
```

The parameters do not get added to the URL and so the expected behavior does not occur.

Any ideas as to why this might occur? I see a bunch of very similar issues but non that quite seem to explain why this might happen with a form setup this way. The only difference I can think of that I can share is that the working customers are all hosted by our company on AWS servers, the customer with issues is self hosted. Apache is used in both cases. But I do not know what could be happening server side that might cause this behavior with a form.

Comment: Re: _"I just have to support it."_ What do you have access to? Do you have access to HTML, CSS and JS?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use `method="POST"` instead of `method="get"` since you are posting data and not retrieving it. What you need to do is change `<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[1].submit();return false;">` to `<input type='submit'>` for the form to work.

Comment: So I tried this and it does technically work. I would think it should have been written that way to start so not sure why they picked GET. But what I can't get over is why this works for some situations and not for all, especially with the same form.